# Kendo Grid Read Action Not Passing Data To Controller Via the .Data Method Call

Tags: razor, kendo-ui, grid

I have a Kendo Grid (MVC Razor) that I am trying to have pass extra data to the controller via the .Data call off of the Read method:

```
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<AssignedSiteGridPoco>()
        .Name("UnAssignedSiteGrid")
        .Filterable()
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .Refresh(true)
            .PageSizes(true)
            .ButtonCount(5))
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.SiteId).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(p => p.SiteName).Title("Site Name").Width(180);
            columns.Bound(p => p.City).Title("City").Width(80);
            columns.Bound(p => p.StateName).Title("State Name").Width(100);
            columns.Command(command => command
                                      .Custom("Add")
                                      .Click("unassignedSiteGridClick")
                           ).Width(90);
        })
        .Scrollable()
        .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
        .Events(events =>
        {
            //events.Change("GridChange");
            //events.DataBound("OnDataBound");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(p => p.SiteId);
                model.Field(p => p.SiteName);
                model.Field(p => p.City).Editable(false);
                model.Field(p => p.StateName).Editable(false);

            })
            .PageSize(15)
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetUnassignedSiteGridDataList",  "Manager").Data("getUserRightName"))

        ))
```

The Javascript block, placed above the grid div, is as follows:

```
 function getUserRightName() {
      return
      {
          UserRightName : "2"
      };
 }
```

And the controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetUnassignedSiteGridDataList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, string UserRightName)
{
    var model = new AssignedSiteGridPoco();
    var siteList = _managerPresentationService.GetUnassignedSiteGridDataList(model);
    return Json(siteList.ToDataSourceResult(request));
}
```

The string value being passed from the view's read method is null in the "UserRightName" string.  According to the examples, it should pass back the text value "2"  My Version of Kendo is: 2014.2.807 InternalBuild.  Is there a problem in this build in this area?

Thanks, 
Steven

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the key name in the json structure into quotes i.e.
change your js function to this:

```
 function getUserRightName() {
        return {'UserRightName':"2"};
    }
```